# Moving Wordpress multisite to localhost for development

Tags: wordpress, server, wamp

I've been trying to copy my multisite of a domain and moving it to

```
C:/wamp/www/at-groep
```

I configured wp-config.php, .htaccess correctly. I created virtual hosts etc. I will give some examples of what I did. The error message I get is:

> If your site does not display, please contact the owner of this
> network. If you are the owner of this network please check that MySQL
> is running properly and all tables are error free.
>
> Could not find site at-groep.local. Searched for table atgroep_blogs
> in database at-groep. Is that right?
>
> What do I do now? Read the bug report page. Some of the guidelines
> there may help you figure out what went wrong. If you’re still stuck
> with this message, then check that your database contains the
> following tables:
>
> atgroep_users - atgroep_usermeta - atgroep_blogs - atgroep_signups
> atgroep_site - atgroep_sitemeta - atgroep_registration_log -
> atgroep_blog_versions

I checked if the tables were there, and they were.

Whilst I expected to expected to see the website's root page.

The configuration is like:

This is my `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /at-groep/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /at-groep/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is my `httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/at-groep">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/at-groep"
    ServerName at-groep.local
    Errorlog "C:/wamp/www/ERROR_LOG_AT_GROEP"
    TransferLog "C:/wamp/www/TRANSFER_LOG_AT_GROEP"
</VirtualHost>
```

This is my `wp-config.php`

```
/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', false );

define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'at-groep.local' );
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

I am using `Wampserver 2.5`.

I expected to see the multisite working on my local machine. Can someone assist me on this one?

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you using? And what version of Apache

Comment: Did you do what the Error message suggested?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Version 2.5 and Apache 2.4.9

Comment: I did what the error message suggested me.. But there are no error's in what I configured, so the problem is quite confusing and difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the syntax for access rights changed in Apache 2.4 so try amending the Virtual Host definition as follows. Also in my opinion it is better to place the `<Directory>...</Directory>` set inside the `<VirtualHost>` section. It at least visually links the 2, although its not illegal to do it the way you did it.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/at-groep"
    ServerName at-groep.local
    Errorlog "C:/wamp/www/ERROR_LOG_AT_GROEP"
    TransferLog "C:/wamp/www/TRANSFER_LOG_AT_GROEP"

    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/at-groep">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If you dont actually want to allow the universe to see your dev site replace

```
Require all granted
```

with

```
Require local
```

If you want to use another PC in your local network as a client use something like this

```
Require local
Require ip 192.168.1
```

Using only the first 3 of the 4 quartiles will allow any ip in that subnet.

Also you will need to add the domain name to your HOSTS file

`C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
::1  localhost

127.0.0.1 at-groep.local
::1  at-groep.local
```

Its also a good idea to read and understand [how to move a WP website](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) there are some changes you will likely have to make to the database as WP stores the URL that was used when the site was originally installed and uses it internally. This can mess you up when moving a site.

SECOND ATTEMPT

The `.htaccess` also looks wrong as you have a Virtual Hosts defined rather then running from a sub folder. See if changing the `RewriteBase` and `RewriteRule` helps.

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Alternatively look at this [WP Doc on `.htaccess`](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) I dont know your exact setup so I cannot suggest anything more specific than this.

Comment: Ima try this.. I already changed hosts file. My site is working, except for the posts and subdomains... I will keep you posted

Comment: Oh and by the way.. I also changed links in the database with a simple replace query. That's already fixed.

Comment: I already did research to those sites.. I studied it but it didn't work, so I tried your changes in the httpd-vhosts.conf file, but also that didn't work :-(

Comment: What version of WP are you running

Comment: just updated to the newest version: 4.3.1 also not the solution

Comment: Well the `.htaccess` you quoted is definitely wrong. I would do a little research in that area for your config. Maybe another question specifically about `.htaccess` for your specific config

Comment: Okay... I will take a look again then.

Comment: Did you invent that `.htaccess` or copy it form the liive site?

Comment: I got it from the live site. Changed it's properties